# initramfs-4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64.img not found

Tags: linux, boot, centos, grub

I get the following error message when i reboot my CentOS 8 system and let grub choose the first boot entry: "initramfs-4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64.img" not found:

[image]

When i choose the second boot entry, im able to boot & login per ssh.
The "rescue" grub entry is dead too, i dont know how this could happen:

[image]

How can i fix the broken entrys and be able to start the newest available kernel?

I have tried to remove & re-install the kernel with:
`yum remove kernel-4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64` & `yum update`

How can i build with `dracut` a new initramfs image with the missing kernel?

Answer (score 3):

The solution was as simple as though.

- Boot with a kernel that works (Press [ESC] to see available boot entrys on startup)
- Rebuild initramfs with dracut

```sh
dracut /boot/initramfs-4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64.img 4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64
```

Login, and see if the right kernel is running:

```sh
uname -r
4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64
```